# Fill NULL values by the closest value below in the same column, with mutiple instances within the same category

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, null

I have just started learning SQL server 2012.

I'm trying to figure out how to fill `NULL` values with the nearest value below.

My data may look something like this:

| date | Product | Order TYPE | Unit price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 1 | Production1 | NULL |
| 2020-01-03 | 1 | Production3 | NULL |
| 2020-01-04 | 1 | Sale1 | 10 |
| 2020-01-05 | 1 | Production4 | NULL |
| 2020-01-06 | 1 | Production5 | NULL |
| 2020-01-07 | 1 | Sale2 | 20 |
| 2020-01-08 | 1 | Production6 | NULL |
| 2020-01-01 | 2 | Production7 | NULL |
| 2020-01-02 | 2 | Production8 | NULL |
| 2020-01-03 | 2 | Sale3 | 15 |
| 2020-01-05 | 2 | Production10 | NULL |
| 2020-01-06 | 2 | Sale4 | 25 |
| 2020-01-07 | 2 | Production11 | NULL |
| 2020-01-07 | 2 | Production12 | NULL |
| 2020-01-07 | 2 | Production13 | NULL |

And I want to replace NULL values like this:

| date | Product | Order TYPE | Unit price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 1 | Production1 | 10 |
| 2020-01-03 | 1 | Production3 | 10 |
| 2020-01-04 | 1 | Sale1 | 10 |
| 2020-01-05 | 1 | Production4 | 20 |
| 2020-01-06 | 1 | Production5 | 20 |
| 2020-01-07 | 1 | Sale2 | 20 |
| 2020-01-08 | 1 | Production6 | `NULL` |
| 2020-01-01 | 2 | Production7 | 15 |
| 2020-01-02 | 2 | Production8 | 15 |
| 2020-01-03 | 2 | Sale3 | 15 |
| 2020-01-05 | 2 | Production10 | 25 |
| 2020-01-06 | 2 | Sale4 | 25 |
| 2020-01-07 | 2 | Production11 | `NULL` |
| 2020-01-07 | 2 | Production12 | `NULL` |
| 2020-01-07 | 2 | Production13 | `NULL` |

In short: replace NULL values with the closes value below within each product group.

- Unit prices can occur multiple times along `product`
- Not replace NULL values if production order have been placed after a sale, where no sales exist after for that given product.

I hope someone can give me some good advice :-) Thanks!

Comment: FYai, SQL Server 2012 is a poor choice of version to start learning on; it only has a couple weeks of extended support left. You would be far better off learning on a 2019 instance.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no choice at this moment. I will take your advice into consideration in the future, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
declare @table as table ([date] date,Product  smallint,OrderType varchar(20),UnitPrice smallint)
insert into @table values 
('2020-01-01',1,'Production1',NULL),
('2020-01-03',1,'Production3',NULL),
('2020-01-04',1,'Sale',10),
('2020-01-05',1,'Production4',NULL),
('2020-01-06',1,'Production5',NULL),
('2020-01-07',1,'Sale2',20),
('2020-01-08',1,'Production6',NULL),
('2020-01-01',2,'Production7',15),
('2020-01-02',2,'Production8',15),
('2020-01-03',2,'Sale3',15)

select * from @table

;with T1 AS (
    SELECT row_number() over (order by (select 1)) AS Id,* FROM @table
)
update T1 set UnitPrice = T2.UnitPrice
--select T1.*,T2.UnitPrice 
from T1 inner join T1  as T2 on T1.Id <= T2.id
where T1.UnitPrice IS NULL AND T2.UnitPrice IS NOT NULL

select * from @table
```